# WIFI DOESN'T WORK UBUNTU 13.04. I'M USING HP PAVILION DM1

Tags: wireless, 13.04

I've instaled ubuntu 13.04 in my notebook,but the wifi doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

connect using Ethernet , then go to  system settings and open Software Source 
now you can find your wifi driver using additional drivers now :)